# Comparing enum values in Flow

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I'm using [flow](https://flow.org/en/) to annotate types in my code.

```
type Bar = 'One' | 'Two';
function foo(b: Bar) : boolean {
  return b === 'Three';
}
```

Is there any way to teach `flow` to report a warning or an error for comparisons with non matching types (`string` in my case)?

[here is the example for test](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwE4wLwwOQHkB2UMwA+mAKgO4D2GA3MAGYCuOAxiAJYU4x0UUAUAIwBc8ZAEoYIgbwA2UBFwDewGDCRQQDJFwFpU6AEQkAFuqgHaAXyA)

**edit:** so it seems not to be possible to do it *with enums*. but, since this is actually an error I encountered, I'd like to express this so that flow will help me flag such a situation.

Any ideas for that?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a way to do this: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3553

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the format `(value: Type)` . In your case that would be:

```
type Bar = 'One' | 'Two';
function foo(b: Bar) : boolean {
  return b === ("Three": Bar);
}
```

Which will show the error.

[Updated example](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwE4wLwwOQHkB2UMwA+mAKgO4D2GA3MAGYCuOAxiAJYU4x0UUAUAIwBc8ZAEoYIgbwA2UBFwDewGDCRQQDJFwFpU6PgCISAC3VRDIxEjG0AvkA).

Comment: while I had hoped the `===` somehow could be made type-safe by itself, this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

this is another way I could think of:

```
type Bar = 'One' | 'Two';

function eq(a: Bar, b: Bar): boolean {
  return a === b;
}
function foo(b: Bar) : boolean {
  // compare b to 'Three'
  return eq(b, 'Three');
}
```

will result in

```
return eq(b, 'Three');
                  ^ string. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of 
function eq(a: Bar, b: Bar): boolean {
                       ^ string enum
```

[to be found here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigcgPIDsJqgH3QBUB3AezQG4AoagMwFcsBjYASzKyggEcAKOAC5YiADRQARsPgIAlMIlkyAGwhwuAb2pQoCCMAYIucFMlQSaAX3pNWHLnSV8pIuVAVLV6qFp0B6PyhmMgBbMERoCShgMmIACz1cbV19Qy5eZ3E0IgSIXFkrIA)